# Is there a way to rotate an object that is a child of a parent with animator?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The animator make the object to rotate so the script I'm using with a raycast is not working.
Only if I disable the animator then when the raycast hit an item the head of the character will rotate look at the item.

but is there a way to make that the player head will rotate look at the item even if the animator is still working ?

[image: Item detected but the player head is not rotating looking at the item]

The script that attach to the player :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Interactable : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform objToRotateLookAT;

    private bool raycastSucceed;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        int layerMask = 1 << 8;

        RaycastHit hit;
        // Does the ray intersect any objects excluding the player layer
        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward), out hit, Mathf.Infinity, layerMask))
        {
            if (!raycastSucceed)
                Debug.Log("Did Hit");
            raycastSucceed = true;
            Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward) * hit.distance, Color.red);

            Vector3 relativePos = hit.transform.position - objToRotateLookAT.position;

            // the second argument, upwards, defaults to Vector3.up
            Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(relativePos, Vector3.up);
            objToRotateLookAT.rotation = rotation;
        }
        else
        {
            if (raycastSucceed)
                Debug.Log("Did not Hit");
            raycastSucceed = false;
            Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward) * 1000, Color.yellow);
        }
    }
}
```

- The player head will rotate facing the item detected only if the animator is disabled. Is there a way to keep the animator active and also to rotate the head facing the detected item ?

Comment: It seems that if I put the code in LadeUpdate instead in FixedUpdate it's working with the animator animations.  but is it a good solution to use LateUpdate for that ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can't make that in Player's animator because you disabled it. But you can change its rotation in another game object. For example, you can put a HeadManager gameObject with an Animator inside. And whenever you want to make the head rotate, you can just make the Bool in animator of HeadManager.

If you have more than 1 object that you want to rotate their head, you can make this HeadManager child of that game object. And when you hit, you can just simply get it's children's animator and make the bool true.

> https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentInChildren.html

You can check this to get the children's animator.